# How to print input through texts (Python)

Tags: python

I want my program to print the value of the variable 'sob' when I write: write("sob")

Code:

```
str = input(">")
sob = input(".")
if str == ('write("' + sob + '")'):
    print(sob)
else:
    print("SYNTAX ERROR")
```

Comment: its not clear what your question is

Comment: Do you mean `if str == 'write("sob")'`?

Comment: Yes, so if the user writes 'write("sob") and the user presses enter then it will display sob. Or any word they write between the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**CODE**

```
sob = raw_input('Type write("sob"): ')
sob = sob.lower()
if sob == 'write("sob")':
    print(sob.lstrip('Type write("').rstrip('")'))
else:
    print("Error")
```

**RESULT**

```
sob
```

Comment: I only want it to display the word sob

Comment: do you want the user to input 'write' or just 'sob'

Comment: I want the user to input the whole thing but it only prints sob

Comment: @MLCLOUD updated again to make it safe against differences in capitalization. The second line casts the input as all lowercase before the comparison is made.

Comment: Thanks! I will test to see if it works, does it work with python 3.x?

Comment: @MLCLOUD for 3.x just change 'raw_input' to 'input'.  Raw_Input no longer exists in 3.x

Comment: Oh yes i already knew that. Im actually building a mini programming language in python - zircon-lang.weebly.com

Comment: Thanks. Do u know how to make a loop so the user can write and print as much as they want.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. I just logged off for tonight. I'll post a solution tomorrow afternoon

Comment: @MLCLOUD I asked a question myself that was similar. You should be able to modify this to fit your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841115/python-input-prompt-go-back

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `input()` use `raw_intput()`:

```
str = raw_input('>')
sob = raw_input(".")

if str == ('write("' + sob + '")'):
        print(sob)
else:
        print("SYNTAX ERROR")
```

`input()` interprets the input you enter as python commands, whereas `raw_input()` returns a string.

Comment: Is there a way I can write input() with nothing in there

Comment: @MLCLOUD What do you mean "with nothing in there"?

Comment: @user3814613 it depends on which version of the Python the OP is using `input()` is correct for Python3.

Comment: Can I write input(">") as input()?

Comment: @MLCLOUD Yes you can, but in this case you should probably use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: Yes, the prompt is optional.

Comment: @user3814613 Again you might want to validate which version of python the OP is using before offering potentially erroneous information. Given the OP is using `print()` this is a python3 construct (unless using `__future__`).

Comment: Is it optional? Dosent seem to be, or maybe something in my code messed it up?

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for the advice. I'll definitely keep that in mind in the future.