# Going back in an if or else statement with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

After some looking around, this is most likely what I'm looking for, but I can't understand it at all, nor can I figure out how to apply it to my code.

[Python Input Prompt Go Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841115/python-input-prompt-go-back)

So basically I'm trying to make a basic text based game and I have multiple doors which will say certain things/drop hints for something to come, so I want to give the user a chance to open all of the doors.

Right now if they choose the wrong door they're forced to go back, which is how I want it, but if they choose the right door they're forced to go forward, I'd like to add a "go back" option but I can't figure out how...
 I'm extremely new to Python so if someone could help me out in extremely simple terms I would really appreciate it, thanks guys, here's my code.

```
#Def#
def purple_door():'''I'd like it to have the option to type "continue" or "go back"'''
print('"You open the door to find a long dark hall, at the end you can see a glowing white light, perhaps a shiny medal! Oooo shiny medal!')
input('continue')

def red_door():
    print('This door opens1')

def orange_door():
    print('This door opens2')

def yellow_door():
    print('This door opens3')

def green_door():
    print('This door opens4')

def blue_door():
    print('This door opens5')

def pink_door():
    print('This door opens6')

#End Def#

#If or Else#

while True:

    door_chosen = input('>')

    if door_chosen in ('Purple', 'purple', 'Purple.', 'purple.'):
        purple_door()
        break

    elif door_chosen in ('Red', 'red', 'Red.', 'red.'):
        red_door()

    elif door_chosen in ('Orange', 'orange', 'Orange.', 'orange.'):
        orange_door()

    elif door_chosen in('Yellow', 'yellow', 'Yellow.', 'yellow.'):
        yellow_door()

    elif door_chosen in('Green', 'green', 'Green.', 'green.'):
        green_door()

    elif door_chosen in ('Blue', 'blue', 'Blue.', 'blue.'):
        blue_door()

    elif door_chosen in ('Pink', 'pink', 'Pink.', 'pink.'):
        pink_door()

    else:
        print('Please type a color stated above.')
#If or else end#
```

Any suggestions for improvement are greatly appreciated.

Edit: I guess I didn't explain well enough my apologies.

Yes when any door other than Purple is chosen, it forces you to choose another until you choose purple, this is what I want to happen.

But let's say someone wants to open all the doors and their first guess was purple, now they have to move on, so what I would like to do is give the option to go back, say.
///Example///
"Choose which door you'd like to open"

Purple

"You open the purple door and come to a hall"
"Continue, or go back"

Go back

"You decide to go back and look at other doors"
///End///

Then you can choose purple and continue when you're ready.
I hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make the `#If Else#` section of your code into a function. From there, you call that function at the end of `purple_door` if some input there == go back. I made some other readability improvements along the way:

```
color_num = {'red': 1, 'orange': 2, 'yellow': 3, 'green': 4, 'blue': 5, 'pink': 6}  # for later use


def purple_door():
    print('"You open the door to find a long dark hall, at the end you can see a glowing white light, perhaps a shiny medal! Oooo shiny medal!"')
    while True:
        choice = input('Continue? ').lower().strip(' .')

        if choice in {'continue', 'yes', 'ok', 'why not', 'may as well'}:
            # Continue the game
            break

        elif choice in {'no', 'back', 'go back', 'do not continue', 'retreat'}:
            main()
            break

        else:
            continue

def main():
    while True:
        door_chosen = input('>').lower().strip(' .')  # lower forces the string to lowercase
                                                      # and strip(' .') removes spaces and periods from the beginning and end
        if door_chosen == 'purple':
            purple_door()
            break

        elif door_chosen in color_num.keys():
            print('This door opens{}'.format(color_num[door_chosen]))  # inserts the number corresponding to the door in place of the {}

        else:
            print('Please type a color stated above.')

main()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked out pretty much how I wanted, one last question, say I want an individual description for each door opened, how do I do that?

Comment: Instead of putting number values in the dictionary, set them to the strings you want to print. Then, instead of `print('This door opens{}'.format(color_num[door_chosen]))` just put `print(color_num[door_chosen])`

Comment: Perfect! Case closed, it's working how I expected it to! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program doesn't allow the user to go back is because you're probably only testing the purple door which contains the `break` statement. Every other door will ask for the user to choose another door:

Also note my changes using `.lower()` to reduce the amount of values you need to check against

```
def purple_door():
    print('"You open the door to find a long dark hall, at the end you can see a glowing white light, perhaps a shiny medal! Oooo shiny medal!')

def red_door():
    print('This door opens1')

while True:
    door_chosen = input('Choose a door colour: ')

    if door_chosen.lower() in ('purple', 'purple.'):
        purple_door()
    elif door_chosen.lower() in ('red', 'red.'):
        red_door()
    else:
        print('Please type a color stated above.')
```

Example output:

```
Choose a door colour: red
This door opens1
Choose a door colour: purple
"You open the door to find a long dark hall, at the end you can see a glowing white light, perhaps a shiny medal! Oooo shiny medal!"
Choose a door colour: black
Please type a color stated above.
Choose a door colour: red.
This opens door1
```